# How to get monitor/display resolution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

As you know, monitors and displays are manufactured with some resolution. I need to get monitor/display resolution. I don't mean resolution of game window/fullscreen, I mean physical resolution of monitor/display.

I need it to work both on Android and Windows.

EDIT :

I just found what i'm looking for is called **NATIVE RESOLUTION**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like i found solution. @Draco18s pointed to Screen class but what i'm looking for is called [Display](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Display.html). Display class allows me to get native size of monitor or display in pixels. Looks like "Screen" class is used only for game window/full screen but for display as hardware device is used "Display" class. It was added to Unity3d very recently with multi-display support, this is reason why very few people knows about its existence.

To be more specific i was looking for `Display.main.systemHeight` and `Display.main.systemWidth`

Comment: Good find, I definitely didn't know about it.

Comment: Note that in the Editor, this returns the resolution set for Game View (or computed from Game View dimensions if using Free Aspect or some Aspect constraint), which may or may not be what you want. The alternative, Screen.currentResolution, returns the display native resolution in the Editor indeed; but beware, in builds, it seems to return the native resolution only not in exclusive fullscreen mode and not using over-display-limit upscaling techniques (saw some comments on https://answers.unity.com/questions/16216/how-to-get-native-screen-resolution.html but could not test everything)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Screen`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html) class is what you are looking for.

Particularly `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`.

Comment: Sadly, no. This give you current resolution, so resolution of game window/fulscreen. As i said in my question: " I don't mean resolution of game window/fullscreen, I mean physical resolution of monitor/display." I need physical resolution of screen because i want use to set current resolution @Draco18s .

Comment: Were you looking at the Unity class? Believe he is referring to the Windows class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8xzhd15.aspx

Comment: @Garrom How about [`Screen.resolutions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-resolutions.html) then?

Comment: @ryeMoss Windows screen class have nothing like Screen.width or Screen.height .About Screen.resolutions, it returns empty array on android, so no.

Comment: @ryeMoss I admit, you are right but question is : Do it work on android ? After all, it is Microsoft's class.

Comment: I'm not positive if there is a universal way to determine screen size. It may be that you need to use two different classes depending on the device type.

Comment: On Android `Screen.width` / `Screen.height` are likely to BE the full screen resolution...unless you've made your app multi-app capable.

Comment: @Draco18s Sadly,no. Same problem as before : It gives me current resolution no physical resolution what i need

Comment: @Garrom [try this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/161281/is-there-a-way-to-android-physical-screen-size.html). I have no idea if it'll work, but it seems like it might.

Comment: @Draco18s thanks but on linked page they getting dpi but i need pixel size of physical screen.